# In node tree, parent.addChild(self) is adding self to self

Tags: python, nodes

I'm building a simple node tree in python.  But when my constructor tries to add the current node as a child of a given parent, the current node *also* adds itself as a child of itself.

Here's my constructor method (and the creation of `children`):

```
children = []

def __init__(self, parent=None, tag="[ROOT]", attrs=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.tag = tag
        self.attrs = attrs
        print "\n", "self:%s ... children:%s" % (self.tag, self.children)
        if parent != None:
            parent.addChild(self)
        print "self:%s ... children:%s" % (self.tag, self.children)
```

Here's my addChild method in the same class (which is supposed to be called for the parent, not the node currently under construction):

```
def addChild(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)
```

Here's the output:

```
foo []
foo [foo]
```

The two lines of output should be the same because the line of code between them should only affect the parent node, not the node currently under construction.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is ``self.children`` constructed? Your ``__init__`` method does not seem to initialize it.

Comment: Where is that output coming from? It doesn't match those `print` statements.

Comment: @Tamas, I changed the code above to indicate where `self.children` is constructed.

Comment: @John Kugelman, I defined `__repr__(self)` to return `self.tag`, so the output I rendered does in fact match the output of the print statements in the `__init__` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect `children` is somehow shared across all of your node objects; we can't see the declaration so I can't say exactly what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

When you initialize children at the class level every instance of your class ends up sharing the same list object.

```
>>> class C:
...  children = []
... 
>>> a = C()
>>> b = C()
>>> id(a.children)
144349644
>>> id(b.children)
144349644
```

Try initializing it in your constructor instead:

```
def __init__(self, parent=None, tag="[ROOT]", attrs=None):
    self.children = []
```